# Process and Thread descriptors

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

This is a question from my homework that I think I wrong ..

> There's a list with various field of classic process descriptor.
>
> For each field, explain if it should be defined at *process descriptor* or *thread descriptor.*
>
> - User name
> - Stack bottom
> - Resources blocking me
> - Primary memory allocated to me
> - Files allocated to me
> - Execution state

I've wrriten that because of `thread` being a `"sub process"` or some `process`

Then the "shared" things should be on the `process discriptor` and the `individual things` should be at the `thread descriptor`.

So:

> "User name": It would go to `process`, because a thread created from a process, and the thread will have the same username like the process.
>
> "Stack bottom": Threads stack is shared, so it don't have bottoms..
>
> "primary memory allocated to me": The same reason as above.
>
> "Filed allocated to me": Same reason
>
> All the above goes to `process descriptor`
>
> "resources blocking me": only one thread can access a resource at once.
>
> "Execution state": Every thread can be `ready`, `blocked` or `run` individually.
>
> These two goes to *thread process*

Can you please tell me If I right or wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mostly right but you have a couple of important mistakes.  Why do you think each of the shared things is shared?  Why do you think each of the individual things is individual?

Comment: @Zack Logic and experience . I didn't find a good source for learning about that.

Comment: Please write down your reasoning for each thing separately.

Comment: @Zack I added this information

Comment: OK. At least one of your statements is incorrect, but I'm not going to tell you which, because if I just tell you, you won't learn anything.  Look over the list again and try to explain *why* you believe that each is shared or not shared.  (Your reasoning, right now, is circular: "this is shared because it's shared.")